# Jenkins SSH issue on Mac OS X installed by homebrew

Tags: macos, ssh, jenkins, homebrew, launchd

I installed Jenkins CI from homebrew (`brew install jenkins`). So, it runs under my own user. Everything works fine except for SSH access to my Git repository. I do not want to create a separate user (e.g. jenkins) to run Jenkins and create separate SSH keys for it. I just want to use my own SSH keys. Accessing my remote git repo on the command-line works fine with my ssh keys, but in Jenkins it does not work. It gives a 'Permission denied (publickey)' error (username and project are obfuscated (`<user>` and `<project>`)):

```
Started by user anonymous
Checkout:workspace / /Users/<user>/.jenkins/jobs/<project>_run_tests/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@456d3d51
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision 093f1641f26632afd1a74c14276ec544356c1d08 (origin/dev)
Checkout:workspace / /Users/<user>/.jenkins/jobs/<project>_run_tests/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@456d3d51
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<user>/<project>.git
ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
ERROR:  (Underlying report) : Error performing command: /usr/local/bin/git fetch -t ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<user>/<project>.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Command "/usr/local/bin/git fetch -t ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<user>/<project>.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

ERROR: Could not fetch from any repository
FATAL: Could not fetch from any repository
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not fetch from any repository
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1012)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:972)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:783)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:765)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:972)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1195)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:568)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:457)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1404)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:230)
```

It seems it is not using my ssh keys to connect to the git server. I tried adding a UserName key to the jenkins launchagent plist, did a restart, but no effect.

How can I make jenkins use my SSH keys to connect to my remote git repo?

Comment: Hmm, when I start jenkins from the command-line, it just works. By doing `/usr/bin/java -jar /usr/local/Cellar/jenkins/1.440/lib/jenkins.war`, there is no problem. So, my question now is: how do I run jenkins from launchd and still have SSH access to my remote git repos?

Comment: Bumping this up. Running into the exact same issue here on Mac OSX 10.7 & Jenkins 1.442 and can't find a solution. Anyone any ideas on this?

Comment: Looking at http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/launchd-dev/2007-November/000081.html, it appears that the .plist file needs to be in a "LaunchAgents" instead of "LaunchDaemons" directory.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how homebrew sets up Jenkins, but apparently it is running in a context where it has no access to your ssh agent and your ssh key is passphrase-protected.

When you run it in a Terminal window, you have SSH_AUTH_SOCK variable in your environment which ssh client uses to authenticate. If you cannot use the ssh agent, you need to remove the passphrase from the ssh key.